# Как рассчитать дату и время окончания работы?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, дата

Я знаю количество затраченного времени на работу, могу вывести дату и время окончания работы, но без учета рабочего времени...и выходных дней.
К примеру работа будет совершаться 5 часов, часы работы с 8 до 16, работу начали в 14 часов, соответственно как мне рассчитать время чтобы показать что завершится она в 11 часов + 1 день

Пробовал через get Day и т.д. Одними проверочными if else не обойтись потому как нужно проверять как входные данные так и выходные Может кто знает как сделать часы в которых 8 часов в сутках?

```
t = new Date()
 firstday = true
 var rest = 5   //рест колво часов на выполнение задания
 
  while (rest > 0){
  if(t.getDay() == 0||6){  //проверяем на выходные
   t.setDate(t.getDate()+ 1)} //пропускаем если выходной
   else {
   if(firstday){
    starthour = t.getHours() //если начинаем с середины дня 
    firstday = false        
    }
    else
    starthour = 10     //начинаем с начала дня
   ti = (19 - starthour) 
   if (rest > ti){ 
     rest = rest - ti
      t.setDate(t.getDate()+ 1)
  }
  else 
   return (t.getDate(), starthour + rest) 
  };
  }
```

Comment: сделать часы с 8 часов в сутках очень просто - делить с остатком продолжительность на 8 часов.

Comment: Продолжительность работы? а что дальше с этим делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С учётом праздников и переноса выходных надёжнее всего перебирать день за днём

```
 пока остаток часов > 0:
     if праздник, выходной: 
         проматываем день
     else (рабочий день): 
        if первый день:
              начало дня = старт работы
        else: 
              начало дня = утро
        t = (вечер - начало дня)
        if осталось больше t:
            отнимаем t часов, проматываем день
        else:
            возвращаем текуший день, начало дня + остаток часов
```

Попробую модифицировать то, что у Вас получилось:

```
t = new Date()
firstday = True
let rest = 5
while (rest > 0){
  if(t.getDay() == 0||6){  
    t.setDate(t.getDate()+ 1)
  }
  else {
    if(firstday){
        starthour = t.getHours()
        firstday = False
    }
    else
        starthour = 10
  ti = (19 - starthour) 
  if (rest > ti){ 
         rest = rest - ti
          t.setDate(t.getDate()+ 1)
  }
  else 
    return t.getDate(), starthour + rest 
}
```

Рабочий код на Python.

```
def calcworkend(rest, startday, starthour, morning, evening):
    day = startday
    while rest > 0:
        if (day + 1) % 7 < 2:
            day += 1
        else:
            workstart = starthour if day == startday else morning
            workstart = min(evening, max(workstart, morning))
            hoursleft = evening - workstart
            if rest > hoursleft:
                rest -= hoursleft
                day += 1
            else:
                return (day - startday, workstart + rest)

print(calcworkend(8, 1, 15, 10, 19)) 
(1, 14)    # 4 часа в понедельник, 4 во вторник
print(calcworkend(8, 1, 3, 10, 19))
(0, 18)    # рано озадачили, в понедельник управились
print(calcworkend(8, 1, 22, 10, 19))
(1, 18)    # поздно озадачили, во вторник все делали
print(calcworkend(8, 5, 15, 10, 19))
(3, 14)  # в пятницу начали, в понедельник закончили
print(calcworkend(8, 7, 15, 10, 19))
(1, 18)  # в воскресенье озадачили, в понедельник поработали
print(calcworkend(32, 4, 18, 10, 19))
(6, 14)  # в четверг начали большое дело, в среду закончили
```

Comment: `t = new Date()
let rest = 5                                     //ЧАСОВ на выполнение работы
while (rest > 0){
   if(t.getDay() == 0||6){                 //проверяем на выходной день
       t.setDate(t.getDate()+ 1)        //проматываем если выходной
   }else{
      if(t.getDay() == 1){
         начало дня = start работы}  // здесь немного не понял
      else{
         начало дня  = утро
         ti = (19 - 10)} //рабочий день с 10 до 19
      if (rest > ti){
         rest - t
      }else{
         return t.getDate()+ 10 + rest //выводим результат?
      }}}`

Comment: `здесь немного не понял`  -в первый день работа началась не в 10 часов, а в момент её запуска - например, в 15 часов

Comment: ок понял, а как тогда проверить чтобы работа не закончилась в нерабочее время например в 10 вечера?`
t = new Date()
let rest = 5
while (rest > 0){
   if(t.getDay() == 0||6){ 
       t.setDate(t.getDate()+ 1) 
   }else{ if(t.getDay() == 1){
     t.setHours(t.getHours() + rest)}  
          else{
         t.setHours(10 + rest)
         ti = (19 - 10)} //что даёт это число?
      if (rest > ti){
         rest - t
      }else{
         return t.getDate()+ 10 + rest //выводим результат?
      }}
}`

Comment: так это проверяется здесь `if (rest > ti)` и происходит перенос на следующие дни

Comment: я правильно заполнил ti = (19-10)?

Comment: Да для не первого дня. Ещё getDay используется для определения дня недели и для определения - первый ли день работы - это, видимо, неправильно, не всегда же с понедельника.

Comment: `t = new Date()
let rest = 5
while (rest > 0){
   if(t.getDay() == 0||6){  
      t.setDate(t.getDate()+ 1)
   }else{
      if(t.getDay() == 1||2||3||4||5){
         t.setHours(t.getHours() + rest)}  
          else{
         t.setHours(10 + rest)
         ti = (19 - 10)} 
      if (rest > ti){         // а почему здесь отнимаем если по
         t.getHours() - t     // идее необходимо добавлять чтобы промотать день*/        
      }else{return t.getDate(),10 + rest 
      }}
}` что-то я упускаю не работает голова уже не варит

Comment: Здесь трудно читать, лучше отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавив  в конце.форматированный псевдокод. Отнимаем -потому что часы на работу потрачены, а день независимо добавляется

Comment: Благодарю за совет, обновил обновил вопрос

Comment: в консоль ничего не выводится, если мне нужно получить дату месяц год а затем и время выполнения то к каждому разветвлению дописывать ритерн или конс лог?

Comment: как увидеть результат?

Comment: не работает, помогите пожалуйста(

Comment: Да всё работает, это же задача на здоровую логику. Привёл код на Python и случаи, которые смог придумать